# How would I figure out all the URL's generated by specific toggle boxes on a website?

Tags: java, python, html, web-crawler

I'm working on a project that checks for updates on a certain clothing website, where you can filter by things such as tops, bottoms, shoes, etc, as well as sizes.

I was planning on parsing the html of the pages to check for updates, but I was wondering if there was any way to check the url of a specific combination of filtering parameters.

Here is the website: https://www.grailed.com/

For example, if I wanted to check what the url of the filter's "all tops" and "size XL" would be, how would I go about doing that?

Prefer the implementation or technologies to be in java or python since that's all I'm comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

User  the fiddler tool analysis http/https data, I found that, the the `www.grailed.com` use the search api to got the user search result.

From the analysis you need simulation the browser send the `POST` request to the search api URL, in the request need change the `X-CSRF-Token`, `Cookie` and the `request content` parameters. You mentioned you wand filter the `size` and the `all tops` checkbox, so you need change the content the **"filters"** parameter, more information, please try some times and found the different.

[image]

Wish you finish it.